# Creating a network with *both* scale-free properties and clusters in NetLogo

Tags: network-programming, netlogo

I'm trying to model a small-scale (100 to 200 agents) social network in NetLogo.

In the nw extension, NetLogo has inbuilt commands for creating random networks (Erdos-Renyi), small-world networks with clusters (Watts-Strogatz) and scale-free (preferential attachment) networks (Barabasi-Albert).

It seems to me that none of these quite cut it for modeling a human society. Human networks certainly are not random, and whilst small-world networks might be better at modeling small-world phenomena and social clustering they lack the hubs which preferential attachment models have. Preferential attachment networks, on the other hand, lack the clusters typical to human communities.

So I'm kind of stuck with this conundrum: I would like to model a social network with both small-world properties and hubs.

Has anyone done anything like this on NetLogo? I've been trying to search but without success. Is there any literature or pseudocode you know of that might be helpful? Thank you!

I've found the following general discussion pieces from scientific literature, but I'm afraid the implementation of these in NetLogo are beyond my current skills:

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s13278-013-0105-0

https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fncom.2011.00011/full#h4 (Section 3.4)

Comment: You need to work out your algorithm - this is not a NetLogo (or programming issue). There are hundreds of different algorithms for generating networks and, you are correct, none of them will generate the complexity of a real social network. You need to work out which network properties you want and find a paper that describes a suitable algorithm. For example, the two papers that you have already found. Then try and write the NetLogo and come back when you have a specific code problem.

Comment: @ropocop: If you haven´t already checked the model library of Netlogo, you might take a look on the 2 sample models "Preferential attachment" and "Small worlds" as a starting point for your programming work.